# Which one sentence?

Tags: meaning

Can someone please help me with the following

Eric stands in front of the mirror.

(1) He looks at himself in the mirror. / (2) He looks at him in the mirror.

Which one is correct? Sentence (1), Sentence (2), or both? Why?

With my thanks

Comment: The first is correct. "Himself" is a reflexive pronoun, and in this instance perhaps one could say it is a "reflective" pronoun!.

Answer (score 1):

Himself is a reflexive pronoun, used after a preposition [ correctly, in your #1 ] or a verb, " emphasizing " the subject of the sentence / clause.

In your #2, the pronoun him refers to someone else previously mentioned.   There is no emphasis aspect, merely a connection to prior info.   Plainly, he is watching another via the mirror.

Hi, from Nam-gu, Busan.